# Unable to activate the Desktop Art plug-in for Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins

I've neither installed, nor upgraded, any packages for a couple of days, yet today Rhythmbox is reporting that it was 'unable to activate plugin Desktop Art.' It worked before I left the computer (at around 03:00), but when I restarted this afternoon it either couldn't or wouldn't.

I presume couldn't, I don't think my box actively resists my expectations. While I understand there could, potentially, be any number of reasons for this, I was wondering if there's a way to find out *why* it can't be activated? Or, of course, if anyone knows of a workaround to re-enable one of the few plug-ins I find to be essential.

Possibly this might be fixed by simply upgrading to Ubuntu 10.10, but I'd rather know what's happening now, than ignoring it and praying.

The only dependencies I could find are the following:

- python 2.5 (or higher), currently I have: 2.6.5,
- gnome-python-desktop, currently locating this package in Synaptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sigh**

Apparently, somehow, the `pythongnome-desktop` package got removed or deleted at some point. Re-installing it seems to have made Rhythmbox much happier and far more amenable. The plug-in's back, and gracing my desktop.

Comment: Because this was so quickly resolved, once I found the dependencies, I'm not sure if the question's worth leaving for others, or whether I should simply delete it? I leave this decision to the mods and community.

Comment: +1 self answers are good, especially on a well-named, well-tagged question; you may save someone the work you did.

Comment: @msw, in which case, I'll leave it for the future.

Answer (score 1):

### 12.04 and later

The desktop-art plugin originally worked with 10.04 but never was advanced through development to work with later versions of Rhythmbox ... which is a shame because it was a great little plugin.

Rolling up my sleeves - its back for the Rhythmbox 2.9x versions:

[image: Imgur]

... and on mouse-over...

[image: Imgur]

**To Install**

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
cd ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins
git clone https://fossfreedom/desktop-art.git
```

or through my PPA as per the linked question

---

#### useful links

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)
- Project website: https://github.com/fossfreedom/desktop-art

Answer (score 0):

You may want to install

```
  python-rsvg
```

Comment: I can't disagree, but why?

Comment: Because the Python bindings for the RSVG library needed to read and write SVG files are necessary.