# Where did Rhythmbox's visualizations in 12.04 go?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

I cannot seem to find the visualization options in Rhythmbox anymore. Were they left out from inclusion in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In 12.04, RhythmBox has been ported to GTK3 (i.e. the GNOME3 UI), and is currently missing quite a bit of the old functionality (including visualization); old plugins are not supported either.
- A visualization plugin is available in experimental GNOME3, but upgrading to this requires upgrading a lot more than RhythmBox and is not recommended.
- For visualization, it's best to wait until 12.10, when the upstream changes from above will probably be included.

  - **For other plugins** (lyrics, etc.), AU mod/superuser fossfreedom has been testing and porting them to his PPA so they will work with the stock Rhythmbox; please see [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins) for which ones are available and how to install them.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I have indeed stumbled across a PPA which offers the visualizations plug-in, though I will just wait for 12.10.

Comment: Yes, that's the PPA but it requires you to upgrade the full Gnome3 to its packages for rbox viz to work :/