# How to display lyrics that are stored in MP3-Tag?

Tags: mp3-tag, lyrics

How can I achieve that goal? I tried many players - banshee, rhythmbox, amarok, exaile... none of them displays lyrics that are already stored in the mp3. They always try to fetch lyrics from the internet. Interestingly, banshee supports STORING lyrics into the mp3 but not READING - I find that annoying...

One player though does it properly - gmusicbrowser. But this piece of software has a so confusing user interface - I don't wanna use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`ffprobe audio.mp3`, output example:

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'катехизис.mp3':
  Metadata:
    genre           : Trip-Hop
    artist          : Meanna
    date            : 2019-06-07 22:28
    title           : Катехизис
    comment         : https://meanna.ru https://vk.com/clubmeanna
    lyrics          : Может быть пора перестать настраивать компас
                    : И наконец то пойти?
                    : А какой ты невротик
                    : по шкале от 1 до 10?
                    : 
                    : Каждый день это миллионы возможностей
                    : Которыми ты не воспользуешься
                    : Сидя в своей конуре
                    : Каждый чертов день
                    : 
                    : Они значит боятся потерять работу
                    : Но не боятся профукать жизнь
                    : Если когда нибудь станешь свободен
                    : Дай знать, скажи
                    : 
                    : Мое время стоит дороже
                    : Чем все ваши гроши
                    : Мое время стоит дороже
                    : Чем все что вы предложить можете
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install plugins in Rhythmbox, including at least one (lLyrics) that displays lyrics, see another question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins).

Besides, I think your question is possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197559/lyrics-on-mp3-id-tag).

Hope that is helpful.