# adding pls to rhythmbox

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

I try to add .pls [radio station](http://somafm.com/) to rhythmbox. I download the file and I click music>import file but nothing happen. I added one station before and it works fine but now it simply does not work. Also when I try to get from the file, click on `open with rhythmbox` I have the error:

```
Couldn't start playback
Problem occurred without error being set. This is a bug in Rhythmbox or GStreamer.
```

I have all [medibuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) installed and I have one radio station already playing. 
I don't know how to proceed from now and what should I check if there is something to fix. Anyone get similar problem?

(Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit Gnome3)

Answer (score 4):

With my version of `rhythmbox` (2.96) on 12.04, the `.pls` radio stream plays fine. Choose a stream from the site you are interested in; I chose [this 128k mp3 stream](http://somafm.com/missioncontrol.pls) from the site you mentioned and added it with Music > New Internet Radio station (as in the screenshot below).

[image]

Then on the sidebar (see screenshot below) click library > radio and the new station will probably be listed in the unknown genre slot. So then just double click the new station there.

It is also important to note that when you import a radio stream `rhythmbox` will sometimes assign a gender to it ('Space Electronica') and sometimes not. So, for example, [this stream](http://somafm.com/wma128/sonicuniverse.asx) was to be found in 'Experimental Nujazz' when imported. If you can't find the station in the program's list, look through the genres or 'unknown' and double click a station if it doesn't play automatically.

If the stream doesn't play correctly, I should choose an alternative, as there are usually several available; for example, on [this page](http://somafm.com/sonicuniverse/) the [asx stream](http://somafm.com/wma128/sonicuniverse.asx) played the best.

[image]

In general, experiment with the different stream options available on the radio site you are interested in as `rhythmbox` has good support for `.pls` and `.asx` feeds, etc, when the necessary `gstreamer` plugins are installed.

If you can't get the `.pls` file working, you could just open it in a text editor and extract the url and then add that as a radio station in `Rhythmbox`, using the process I mentioned earlier in my answer.

---

You could also try installing the excellent `rhythmbox-plugin-radio-browser` from the [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out) of one of our moderators, [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom); do **not** install the version in the repositories as that version does not work with the current `Rhythmbox`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-radio-browser
```

You have to enable it by going to edit > plugins first.

[image]

More on the plugins available is explained here:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

Comment: Strangely enough it does not show in my Rhythmbox and I don't have a clue why. Previously with ubuntu 10.04 it was not a problem to add a radio station in the way you described. Now with ubuntu 12.04 it simply does not work.

Comment: @tomasz74 see my edit.