# Rhythmbox missing dependencies on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, rhythmbox

I have a brand new installation of Ubuntu 18.04.

When I try to stream radio Rhythmbox I get the error

```
Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in
```

I have looked at the dependencies of Rhythmbox using:

```
apt-cache depends rhythmbox
```

and checking the libraries one by one using, e.g.

```
ldconfig -p | grep libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
```

and this library appear to be missing.

I have downloaded *libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.16.2-4_amd64.deb* and attempted to install it using

```
sudo dpkg -i libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.16.2-4_amd64.deb
```

But I get th error

```
dpkg: error processing archive libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.16.2-4_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64

[Edit 20200418 11:52 BST]
```

I also get the message

```
Additional Multimedia Codec Required
An application is requesting additional multimedia codecs
```

I have run

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

What can I do?

Comment: I guess you made a mistake somewhere, this package is available for Ubuntu 18.04 in official repo https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgstreamer-plugins-base&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all no need to download .deb

Comment: what happens when you run `sudo apt install libgstreamer-plugins-base` ?

Comment: @JoKeR  Unable to locate package libgstreamer-plugins-base. Th install was from the ISO

Comment: Did you open the repositories? You can [look here](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-repositories/)

Comment: @JoKeR main, universe, restricted and multiverse are all checked in Sotware & Updates

Comment: that is weird, what is the output for `uname -a` ?

Comment: @JoKeR 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: bionic (18.04LTS) (libs): GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.2 [security]: amd64 i386

Comment: it seems like you didn't upgrade the distro to ubuntu18.04.2

Comment: run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: @JoKeR done that and restarted the PC. Still get the same output from `uname -a`

Comment: That is really confusing why you can't locate it if it's available for 18.04

Comment: Here's similar topic https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the message from Rhythmbox is misleading. I was trying to play stations that require you to register and sign-in (BBC). Rhythmbox was giving these misleading error messages that sent me off down the wrong track.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583456/how-to-play-bbc-radios-music-live-on-rhythmbox-after-bbc-stops-wma-streams-febr) has solved my problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Open Rhythmbox and in the Activities bar at the top left of the screen you will see it listed with a small down arrow by its side.

[image]

Click on the down arrow and you will be presented with a drop down menu amongst which is listed Plugins.

[image]

You can then configure plugins as required.

If there are no plugins present, you can install them by following these steps in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install -y rhythmbox-plugins
```

The -y flag assumes yes and silently install.

[Reference](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/rhythmbox-plugins)

Comment: No Plugins in the menu, only Help, About and Quit

Comment: Ok found it from the Tools menu. How does this help with missing plugins?

Comment: I've added some further info about installing plugins.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't help. I've added another error message to my question