# How do I change Rhythmbox's visible column order?

Tags: rhythmbox

How to change Rhythmbox's Visible Columns Order instead of "Title - Genre - Artist - Album" to be "Title - Artist - Album - Genre" ?

Comment: It's ridiculous but to be knowledge it's not possible. There's a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/36413).

Answer (score 3):

Rhythmbox does not have this capability built in.  It is a request that's been hanging around since [2003](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119406).

However, Rhythmbox does have the ability to include external plugin modules - these provide extra capabilities and because of Rhythmbox's rich API allows those modules to actually change core Rhythmbox capabilities.

Thus - this is what I've done.  I've adapted my plugin called alternative-toolbar to include just this capability - you can now drag by the column header to any position you required.

before & after…
[image]
Artist has been moved to the more logical position after the title & the genre has been moved from the end to a more prominent position.

---

To install this, use the package `rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar` from my PPA as explained in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins/147943#147943).

Alternatively, hop over onto the [project website](https://github.com/fossfreedom/alternative-toolbar) and install via Git or stable release.

In all cases you need v0.16 or later.

[Source](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/12/28/little-things-matter/) for this answer is my blog.