# Rhythmbox save current song after exit

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, music

How can set Rhythmbox to save automatically the current song when exiting?

The scenario:

1. I have the following playlist

   - *Song 1*
   - *Song 2* `[playing]`
   - *Song 3*
   - *Song 4*
2. *Song 2* is playing. I exit Rhythmbox (I close it or I power off the computer).
3. When I start the application again (e.g. after powering on the computer) it plays *Song 1*.

How can I set it to play *Song 2*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a plugin like [Remember The Rhythm](https://github.com/owais/remember-the-rhythm) which will remember the last playing song and playback time, source (radio station, playlist), browser values (genre, album, artist).

To install **Remember The Rhythm** you can use the following commands in terminal if you use Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:loneowais/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remember-the-rhythm
```

If you use a newest Ubuntu version than 12.04, then you must to install it manually:

- [Download](https://github.com/owais/remember-the-rhythm/archive/master.zip) the zip package.
- Unzip the `remember-the-rhythm-master.zip` file:

  ```
  unzip /path/to/remember-the-rhythm-master.zip -d /path/to/extract
  ```
- Install Remember The Rhythm:

  ```
  cd /path/to/extract/remember-the-rhythm-master
  sudo make install
  ```

After you install it with success, open Rhythmbox player, go to **Rhythmbox** → **Plugins** and enable **Remember the Rhythm** plugin:

[image: Remember the Rhythm plugin]

Comment: It works as expected. Thanks! Note that I needed to change `Loader=python` in `Loader=python3` via `sudo vim /usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/remember-the-rhythm/remember-the-rhythm.plugin`.

Answer (score 3):

### Remember the Rhythm

This is a nice little plugin created a few years back but will solve this.

It is available in either PPA form for all versions from RB2.96 through to RB3.0.

Alternatively you can install from Git if you dont like PPA's for your system.

Lets start with the PPA version.  I'll be upfront - this is my PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-remembertherhythm
```

Finally enable the plugin in your plugins menu.

If you want to install from Git try the following for rhythmbox versions RB2.96 to 2.99:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/owais/remember-the-rhythm.git
cd remember-the-rhythm
sudo make install
```

To uninstall:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

If you are using RB3.0 then the following instructions apply:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/owais/remember-the-rhythm.git
cd remember-the-rhythm/src
```

using your favourite text editor edit the file `remember-the-rhythm.plugin`

Change the line from `Loader=python` to `Loader=python3` and save

```
cd ..
sudo make install
```

#### Rhythmbox 3.0 on Saucy

If you are a saucy user and have Rhythmbox 3.0 installed via either my PPA or Jacobs PPA then you'll need to edit your sources from `saucy` to `trusty`

[image: pic]

[image: pic]

*shameless promotion to [my blog](http://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/installing-rhythmbox-3-0-plugins-the-easy-way) that describes this and much more*

---

Linked Question:

[How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

Comment: Good catch - edited ! :)

Comment: the plugin doesn't seem to work on jammy (22) ubuntu/rhythmbox.   Ubuntu doesn't like the ppa so I pulled source and did make install instead. I see the plugin appear in the list in rhythmbox but when trying to tick it it just shows an error symbol