# Can Rhythmbox fetch cover arts from YouTube?

Tags: rhythmbox

Is it possible for Rhythmbox to fetch the cover art for a song that was downloaded from YouTube to show the cover art instead of the blank, white icon?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of is the strictest answer.

If you have a closer look at the screenshot, the song title, artist and album are a little messed up.

You need to:

1. Either right click the track in rhythmbox and change those values that you see to what they are seen within LastFM / MusicBrainz, Or
2. use an track editor such as Picard or EasyTag and actually change the ID3 tags (if an .mp3 track) for the song title, artist and album

The latter option is better since this actually changes the audio track itself.

The first option changes sometimes does not write the tags to the audio track - it writes it just to the internal database.  Writing to the audio track is only supported for some audio types - think from memory .ogg and .mp3.

Once corrected - make sure you have the coverart search plugin enabled and play the track.  You album art should be found ... again this is dependent that the album art is actually available on LastFm / MusicBrainz.

---

If the album art is not available then you can update the album art by dragging and dropping a suitable .png/.jpg file onto that white square.

Thus grab a screen-shot from the youtube video and save as a .png and drop the .png/.jpg onto that square.

These Q&A explains further:

- [How do I change or delete the album cover image shown in rhythmbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334298/how-do-i-change-or-delete-the-album-cover-image-shown-in-rhythmbox)
- [How can I get Rhythmbox to display the correct album cover art?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454418/how-can-i-get-rhythmbox-to-display-the-correct-album-cover-art)

Comment: Thank you! What if a song is only available as a video on YouTube where it features an image in the video? Can Rhythmbox fetch these, too?

Comment: Again - sort of - see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks again! The dragging and dropping of the image file onto the white square does work!