# The ArtSearch plugin has been deactivated in Rhythmbox.

Tags: 14.04, rhythmbox, plugins

I want to install Album Art Search in the Rhythmbox.

Like [image: this]

But when I select the plug-in appear for me error:

Conflicting plugin found.
The ArtSearch plugin has been deactivated

See the pic [image: here]

I already install Rhythmbox Plugins overview [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

How can I use this Album Art Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a little bit of confusion here...

The plugin you mentioned is actually called *AlbumArtSearch* and is available through the package `rhythmbox-plugin-albumartsearch`.

The above package is only available for Rhythmbox v2.96 to v2.98 users.  Unfortunately the author - nor anybody else has forked the project to maintain it for later v2.99 & v3.0+ users - hence it is not in the PPA in question.

Thus to the challenge ... look over at the [project website](https://github.com/luqmana/rhythmbox-plugins) and fork the project.  Fix it up and contact me through Launchpad and I'll include it within my PPA.

Back to your issue...

The conflicting message is because you were actually trying to re-enable the default Rhythmbox plugin called *CoverArt Search*.  This plugin is superseded by the *CoverArt Search Providers* plugin that you have installed instead - the same functionality and more is available through *CoverArt Search Providers*.

---

Lastly - you might like to know that part of the *Album Art Search* functionality was actually incorporated into my plugin *CoverArt Browser* - just click on the album and the covers from Google are displayed in the Covers tab.

[image: Imgur]

I've got a [wiki page](https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser/wiki/How-to-find-great-coverart) that describes this