# Embedding Tags in Rhythmbox Properties...Is it Possible?

Tags: rhythmbox, music

I am currently ripping my entire CD collection and use Picard to do the auto-retagging before I add the files to my Rhythmbox library.  Occasionally Picard tags mp3s/flacs incorrectly (an album cover might be missing from a single track within an album for example).

As a result I add the missing piece of artwork using Rhythmbox properties but its not embedded into the file.  is it possible to embed tags in Rhythmbox?  If not what is the best approach to make these minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another great tool is `kid3-qt` I use it sometimes.

```
sudo apt-get install kid3-qt
```

Though I use Guayadeque as default music player, it has everything built-in and can automatically embed tags into files.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:anonbeat/guayadeque
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guayadeque-svn
```

Comment: Its good to know the applications you suggest can do the job and I'm open to changing my workflow (reluctantly) if the answer to my question is "No" (Rhythmbox properties cannot embed tags).

Comment: maybe [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins) be interesting for you ;)