# Updated:(New info added) Offline installing Video Player & Rythmbox plugins in Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid

Tags: plugins

I don't have the plugins to play MP3s with rythmbox or video player in Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid. Where can I find offline packages to install it manually &  get the players working with other formats except just .ogg
Ok so here is whats neede to play mp3 formatted audio files within Rhythmbox.
MPEG layer 1/2/3 audiodecoder.

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

Comment: Nope that didn't do it for me. I'm new to ubuntu and don't know if I'm searching/downloading the correct plugin. I don't wannabe spoon fed with this stuff but it's hard not knowing what file name to look for. More assistance please. Lol

Comment: Ok *sigh* so again I went to the ppa launchpad of  foss freedom buuut, I still don't know what packge to download to get rythmbox playing mp3 and other types of audio code.

Comment: Ok so googled a bit and found that I have to install ubuntu-restricted-addons_22_amd64.deb & ubuntu-restricted-extras_63_amd64.deb so this installed but I'm missing something, what else do I havto install to get mp3 formats playing in Rhythmbox 3.1 ? Here is a link to Rhythmbox 3 plugins. https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Plugins/ThirdParty#Rhythmbox_3_Plugins

Comment: I needed this. Download Page forlibmpg123-0_1.20.1-2_amd64.deb on AMD64 machines http://goo.gl/50lfOF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is, on the offline system, run

```
sudo apt-get install -s ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This will **not** install (it is just a simulation), but it will show you the dependencies packages that you need. In my case the output is

```
davide@brenna:~$ sudo apt-get install -s ubuntu-restricted-extras 
[sudo] password for davide: 
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
I seguenti pacchetti saranno inoltre installati:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra flashplugin-installer gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
  libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra-56 ubuntu-restricted-addons
[...]
```

So I need to install also `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra flashplugin-installer gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra-56 ubuntu-restricted-addons` to make it work.

Look for these packages [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) - i386 or amd64 depends on whether you installed a 32 bit or a 64 bit distribution - download and install them by hand.

Comment: tnx.. My previous comment about the mpg codec failed. I've installed the decoder but still nothing. So gonna go abd follow your guide.

Comment: sudo apt-get install -s ubuntu-restricted-extras.  Reading package lists....  Done. Building dependency tree Reading state information....  Done.  ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version. 0 upgraded,  0 newly installed,  0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: This is strange. Have you force-installed the packages before? If so, you might want to recover their dependencies via `apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-addons` and do the same.

Comment: Ok so I've been busy, all ducking day long downloading this, downloading that package an now still rhythmbox don't play mp3 and the video player don't play mp4 and give error: Required plugin could not be found: Videos requires to install plugins to play file of following types: -MPEG-4 AAC decoder. -H.264 decoder. So I've installed the ffmpeg 2.5.8 & it's required libs. But still no mp3/mp4 audio/video sound. Any advice? If you nee screenshot I can share via G+

Comment: Ok sooooo I got Rhythmbox to play mp3 format, not yet sure bout the other audio formats. I think,except all the other lib & core packages,, is that gstream was culprit to this whole fiasco. The video player still error me for an MPEG-4 Video decoder. So I'm tired and wil go figure that out when I rise.

Comment: Why don't you use VLC? It comes with all the codecs already. Unfortunately going through dependencies is always a long and messy process. It would be better to connect the computer for a short time, update it, install what you need and then you are done.

Comment: Ok so how do I download vlc from another internet source and ibstall mannually on ubuntu? And yes its a crack in the ass to go through all those dependencies. But, I've learned some stuff.

Comment: Same way, it's in the repos ;) `sudo apt-get install -s vlc` then go on the website as before and download it from there, with the needed dependencies.

Comment: sudo apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-addons Outputs for me, Recommends: <gtreamer0.10-plugins-ugly> Recomends: <gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly> Recommends: <flashplugin-installer> Recommends: < gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad> Recommends: <gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad> Recommends: <gstreamer1.0-libav> Recommends: <gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3> Recommends: gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 Recommends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extras Recommends: <oxideqt-codecs-extra>

Comment: Oh and next: sudo apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-extras Gives me           ubuntu-restricted-extras Depends: ubuntu-restricted-addons Recommended: <ttf-mscorefonts-installer Recomends: <unrar> Recommends: <gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse Recimmends: <libavcodec-extra>

Comment: I've got vlc installed and working. Just the new version of vlc's equalizer suck ass. And also before I could install vlc I had to install vlc-nox & aaaaall it's dependencies. But atleast can watch vids and L2m. Thanx mate.